# Grails logging auto inject

Tags: grails, logback

I use grails 3.0.2 and logback. How can I use this logger in my code, can I somehow autoinject it, like log.debug() in grails 2.x which was using org.apache.commons.logging.Log?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

add the [`@Slf4j`](https://github.com/groovy/groovy-core/blob/master/src/main/groovy/util/logging/Slf4j.java) annotation on your class.

> This local transform adds a logging ability to your program using
>   LogBack logging. Every method call on a unbound variable named *log*
>   will be mapped to a call to the logger. For this a *log* field will be
>   inserted in the class. If the field already exists the usage of this transform
>   will cause a compilation error. The method name will be used to determine
>   what to call on the logger.
>
> ```
> log.name(exp)
> ```
>
> is mapped to
>
> ```
> if (log.isNameLoggable() {
>    log.name(exp)
> }
> ```
>
> Here name is a place holder for info, debug, warning, error, etc.
>   If the expression exp is a constant or only a variable access the method call will
>   not be transformed. But this will still cause a call on the injected logger.